# What is the difference between `*` and `>` in IRB prompt?

Tags: ruby, prompt, irb

I sometimes try to type a script for some specific commands, for example `attire_accessor` [sic]. Ruby gives `*` at the end of a prompt instead of `>` in interactive mode. What is the difference?

Comment: I will delete my answer if you hate it.

Answer (score 1):

- The `>` prompt means there is no uncompleted expression, i.e., a new expression is expected.
- The `*` prompt means it is in the middle of an uncompleted expression.